# MySQL Count values that does not begin with m?

Tags: mysql, json

I need mysql query that counts from channels table in JSON format values that does not begins with m.

So this is my table:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM channels;
+----+---------------------+---------+----------+
| id | sort                | bouquet | reseller |
+----+---------------------+---------+----------+
|  1 | ["m1","1","2","11"] | ["1"]   |        1 |
| 27 | ["1","2"]           | ["28"]  |        1 |
| 39 | []                  | ["33"]  |        1 |
+----+---------------------+---------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So if i select id1 i need to get count result 3 (ignoring m1). My all sort values will be numbers from 1 to 99999 that needs to be count and all markers will be starting from m1 to m99999 that needs to be ignored when counting.

So here are examples:

```
["m1","1","2","11","m2","12","31"] => count will be 5

["1","m1","m2","m3"] => count will be 1
```

So ignore all string that begins with m and count all others numbers in JSON value.

How can i do that in MySQL? SUBSTRING? JSON_SEARCH? I have no clue if someone could give me hint or example code how to do that..i need this to count channels from sort field and not counting markers (starting with m) so that i have real number of channels in clicked bouquet.

Thanks.

Comment: And you're determined to store non-normalised data?

Comment: Yes i must store in JSON because i build channel editor and using each row value for each channel is very long read and write so i pickup json store because it is faster and lot easy to see what is order of channels..and writing sql query for json reading is more dificull but it can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution using [`JSON_SEARCH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) and [`JSON_LENGTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-attribute-functions.html#function_json-length):

```
SELECT JSON_LENGTH(sort) - IFNULL(JSON_LENGTH(JSON_SEARCH(sort, 'all', 'm%')), 0) 
FROM channels
WHERE id = 1;
```

Without the `WHERE` you get the following output:

```
3
2
0
```